# Unable to create an object of type 'OrderDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time,

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a `HotChocolate GraphQL Function` project template in .NET 6. In this project, I have installed these nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework" Version="13.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.16">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
  
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AzureFunctions" Version="13.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Types.Analyzers" Version="13.1.0">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

When I run `add-migration initial`, the build succeeded but I have this error `Unable to create an object of type 'OrderDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

This is the `OrderDbContext.cs`

```
public class OrderDbContext : DbContext
{
    public OrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDbContext> options)
: base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OrderingDbConnection");

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<OrderDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        builder
            .AddGraphQLFunction()
            .AddQueryType<Query>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work well with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`. Have you tried creating a `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` instead, as suggested by the link?

Comment: When I compare it with another working example, https://github.com/markheath/funcs-todo-csharp, it is also using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: I know that using `GetEnvironmentVariable` works when running the project, so you can absolutely use that, but does the linked project use migrations the same way that you want to do?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on the link? The migration tool must create an instance of DbContext for its work. To do this, you must provide it either a host with registered services, or a constructor without parameters, or a design-time factory.